# Can a character drop a net as a free action and have it affect an enemy under them?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

For example: A Raptoran is in flight and is holding a net. His movement from his previous turn ended 20 feet directly above an enemy. At the start of his next turn could he, as a free action, drop said net causing it to trap the enemy below him and then dive attack another enemy? Or, would the dropped net fail to open correctly and fall harmlessly into the enemy's square?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**No.**

SRD:

> A net is used to entangle enemies. When you throw a net, you make a ranged touch attack against your target.

Simply dropping it isn't a ranged touch attack, and at best would merely count as an improvised weapon dealing falling damage.

---

Something to consider:

> A net must be folded to be thrown effectively. The first time you throw your net in a fight, you make a normal ranged touch attack roll. After the net is unfolded, you take a –4 penalty on attack rolls with it. It takes 2 rounds for a proficient user to fold a net and twice that long for a nonproficient one to do so.

Credit: Ben-Jamin

Comment: I would expand to include the fact that merely dropping a net, even if u actually hit the target square on the head, would not mean it deployed properly if it wasn't thrown.